# IndexError while making a query in a TestCase

Tags: django, testing

I have a very simple test as follows:

```
import models
from django.test import TestCase

MyViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.trip = models.Trip.objects.order_by('?')[0]

   def test_something(self):
       # Blah Blah
```

whenever i run test it throws the error mentioned below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amyth/Projects/test/trips/tests.py", line 8, in setUp
    self.trip = models.Trip.objects.order_by('?')[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also tried changing the query to `models.Trip.objects.all()[0]` and it still throws the same error. What's strange is if I use any of the above queries within the shell it works. Then howcome it is not working within a test ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) on testing in django. A new 'test' database is created, and your 'production' database is not used. Unless you create Trip entries in the TestCase `setUp` method, it is empty. Also, after each TestCase is run, the database is truncated, so if you need to use the Trips in multiple TestCases, you will need to create the database entry for it in each TestCase `setUp`.